# Extracting max min where the value of each key is a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following, where the value for each key is a dictionary itself:

```
dict = { "key1": { "sal":24000, "xy":32, "age":54}
         "key2": { "sal":40000, "xy":22, "age":14}
         "key3": { "sal":50000, "xy":12, "age":64} }
```

I want to extract the maximum and minimum salary from here.
i.e my output should be
24000 when I search for the minimum and
50000 when I search for the maximum.

How do I go about this?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you done any research or made any attempts at coding this? Also, using `dict` as a name means you can't use the `dict()` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
max(dict.itervalues(), key=lambda x: x['sal'])
```

Just the same for minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Full solution:

```
dic = {"key1": { "sal": 24000, "xy": 32, "age": 54},
       "key2": { "sal": 40000, "xy": 22, "age": 14},
       "key3": { "sal": 50000, "xy": 12, "age": 64} }

max_sal = max(dic.values(), key=lambda x: x['sal'])['sal']
min_sal = min(dic.values(), key=lambda x: x['sal'])['sal']

>>> max_sal
50000
>>> min_sal
24000
```

**Note**: Don't use `dict` as your variable name. It is a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of getting the highest salary using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
max(dict.itervalues(), key=operator.itemgetter('sal'))
```

Extracting salaries first, then apply `max`:

```
max(d['sal'] for d in dict.itervalues())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use list comprehension to find the max/min of each inner dictionary, and then return the max/min of all of that:

MAX: `max([max(dict[key].values()) for key in dict])`

MIN: `min([min(dict[key].values()) for key in dict])`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract both of them in a single call reducing the dict values:

```
>>> dict = { "key1": { "sal":24000, "xy":32, "age":54},
         "key2": { "sal":40000, "xy":22, "age":14},
         "key3": { "sal":50000, "xy":12, "age":64} }
>>>import sys
>>>max, min = reduce(lambda (max, min), v: (max if max > v else v, min if min < v else v), [e["sal"] for e in dict.values()], (0, sys.maxint))

>>> max
50000
>>> min
24000
```

Explaining the code above:

Lambda function that takes a tuple with the max and min and a value, changing the values of the tuple for the value taken if the conditions are passed.

```
lambda (max, min), v: (max if max > v else v, min if min < v else v)
```

Taking all the salaries from the dict into a list:

```
[e["sal"] for e in dict.values()]
```

Initial tuple values for the reduce method:

```
(0, sys.maxin)
```

`reduce` just takes values once after another feeding the lambda function.